# Cant get file location for downloads from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
<?php
include "config.php";
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id=$_GET['id'];
    echo'$id';
    $stat=$db->prepare("select * from contents where cid='$id'");
    $stat->bindParam(1,$id);
    $stat->execute();
    $data=$stat->fetch();

    $file='files/'.$data['document'];
    if(file_exists($file)){
        header('Content description: '.$data['document']);
        header('Content-length'.filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

This is a script to download files from a phpmyadmin database (named contents)which contains the columns docid,cid,document,notification.
When i execute this script i get the following error message:

> Internal Server Error

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

> Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

> More information about this error may be available in the server error log

I'm a complete beginner to both stack overflow as well as programming, so please forgive me if there is any error in my code or in my formatting of the question

Comment: `Content description` isn't a valid HTTP header...

Comment: so what should i do to resolve this error?

Comment: First thing: have a look into the webservers error logs, they should contain more information about the actual error (internal server error = http 500 -> always check log files)

Comment: There is no such thing as `phpmyadmin database`. PHPmyadmin is a UI for interacting with mysql database.

Comment: The issue likely actually is the incorrect prepared statement usage. You need to use a placeholder in the query. `select * from contents where cid=?` Also if you only need `document` change the `*` to that in the select list.

Comment: Remove the `echo'$id';` line. Calling `header()` after an `echo` will trigger a "headers already sent" warning. This should only be a warning though and not enough reason to trigger a 500 error. You should check your server logs or [enable error reporting temporarily](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1053424/1941241).